# How do I calculate the determinant of the functional matrix?

Tags: derivatives

The figure $f: \left [0,\infty \right ),\left \lfloor 0,2\pi \right \rfloor, \left [-\pi/2,\pi/2\right ]$
$\begin{pmatrix}r\\\varphi \\\vartheta \end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}rcos\vartheta\cos\varphi \\rcos\vartheta sin\varphi \\rsin\vartheta\end{pmatrix}$
corresponds to the introduction of spherical coordinates in R3.